# TeX is bunching up in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

I used to get this problem on and off, but now it's mostly on.  The TeX that I see doesn't have spaces in the right place, or something; it is getting really hard to read.  I'm using Chrome 7.0.503.0 dev on Windows 7.

Comment: Historically, there has never been much effort put into fixing bugs that only pop up in the dev version. Can anyone confirm that this bug occurs in the stable version of Chrome?

Comment: Issues with dev versions of browsers are explicitly not considered bugs with SE.  That said, I'll be right back here on this question to tell you whether or not I have the same issue with 7.0.503.0/Mac when I eventually let Chrome restart.

Comment: I have the "tex bunching up" bug in Chrome too (5.0.375.127) -- is it related to "The symbols are misaligned. What happened?" on http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs/  ??

Comment: Looks good on Chrome 5. Have you tried Shift+Refresh?

Comment: in Chrome 6 beta on Windows everything looks OK

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with the same version.

Comment: I'm also getting this problem in Chrome 5.0.375.127, but as suggested by KennyTM, hitting Shift+F5 resolves it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone.  The bug is gone at the moment, which is strange.

Comment: I posted about this some days ago too. I have the problem with 7.0.517.41 (on 64-bit, Linux). Shift + F5 doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Same issue here, sometimes Shift+f5 gets it, not always. Win7+Chrome 6.0.472.55 here.

Comment: Yep, having same problem, Windows 7 and Chrome 7.0.517.44 (64 bit).  Shift+F5 not working either.

Comment: I had the same problem, I posted about this some time ago.

Answer (score 3):

I can also reproduce the problem on Chrome 8. It's odd because on an earlier version of Chrome on a different laptop I encountered no problems, and once on this laptop the font loaded correctly. But then it went back to not working again. All fonts were downloaded, according to Chrome's resource tracker, but the spacing remains weird.

Anyway, I was able to fix my problem by installing the MathJax fonts locally. On Windows, you just need to [download the fonts](http://www.mathjax.org/help/fonts/) and drag them into the Windows/Fonts folder. MathJax detected that I had the necessary fonts locally so avoided any remote font problems.

Note: I've read [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users/browse_thread/thread/ca47a89faa094ca5/efef10a46c6baa4a?#efef10a46c6baa4a) that sometimes MathJax might not be recognizing local fonts; in that case, I don't know how much the above will help.

Edit: I don't know how long this link will be valid, but using [these fonts](http://www.mathjax.org/dl/MathJax-Font-Update.zip) instead also work. These are the actual fonts that MathJax tries to download onto your computer (I think), so may look better than the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

I STILL have this problem! Shift-F5 now has stopped working completely. Can we please get some resolution. It is essentially impossible to use the site like this...

Comment: also, i think no-repro is an inappropriate tag since many people above have been able to reproduce it.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: 8.0.552.28 beta right now, but before I was using 6.0.472.55 and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, I attach screenshot. Using Chrome 8.0.552.224.
*Shift-F5* sometimes fixes it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The TeX also bunches up randomly on Chrome for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue. I just updated chrome. Running 8.0.552.237 on Windows 7.

It works fine on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Why it doesn't get fixed? It was stated 6months ago. And in 9 version of chrome same problem...